# Hadoop accepting custom arguments for Driver

Tags: java, hadoop

How do I pass custom arguments to my hadoop mapreduce job?

For instance, if in my driver I have:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    try {
        String one = args[0];
        String two = args[1];
        System.out.println(two);
        System.out.println(one);
    }
    catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
        System.out.println("ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException caught");
    }
    finally {

    }
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "word count");
    job.setJarByClass(WordCount.class);
    job.setMapperClass(TokenizerMapper.class);
    job.setCombinerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
    job.setReducerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[2]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[3]));
    System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
 }
```

After I jar the file, when I run the command:

```
hadoop jar str1 str2 /home/bli1/wordcount/wc.jar /user/bli1/wordcount/input /user/bli1/wordcount/testout
```

I get:

```
Not a valid JAR: /nfsdata/DSCluster/home/bli1/wordcount/str1
```

Answer (score 1):

The arguments need to go after the JAR file reference, such as:

```
hadoop jar /home/bli1/wordcount/wc.jar str1 str2 /user/bli1/wordcount/input /user/bli1/wordcount/testout
```